# Common ancestor in a titan graph..

Tags: graph, gremlin, titan

In a titan(hbase) graph, i would like to get common ancestors for given nodes. 
Using gremlin is there any way we can get the common ancestors? 
Or any other Utils / libs available to find common ancestors in a Titan graph for given nodes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll make some assumptions on exactly what you're looking for here, but maybe this answer will help inspire you to come up with what you are looking for.  I used the [toy graph](https://raw.github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/master/doc/images/graph-example-1.jpg) to demonstrate this approach and assumed the edges directionally pointed to children.  Obviously this isn't a perfect tree, but there's enough data there to at least demonstrate the traversal.  The following shows the "children" for whom I wanted to find ancestors:

```
gremlin> g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:6 edges:6]
gremlin> children = [g.v(2),g.v(5),g.v(6)]
==>v[2]
==>v[5]
==>v[6]
```

I can recursively loop up through the tree through ancestors and see the paths as follows:

```
gremlin> children._().in.loop(1){it.loops<5}{true}.path
==>[v[2], v[1]]
==>[v[5], v[4]]
==>[v[5], v[4], v[1]]
```

The above line caps the loop at 5 steps away from the ancestor and the `{true}` closure simply means to output values at all steps of the loop.  A common ancestor would be one where the each path terminates more than once:

```
gremlin> children._().in.loop(1){it.loops<5}{true}.groupCount.cap.next().findAll{it.value>1}
==>v[1]=2
```

In this sense `v[1]` is the only common ancestor among the three child nodes and only 2 of the 3 child nodes share that ancestor.  To make it more interesting, let's connect vertex `6` to vertex `4` and re-execute the traversal:

```
gremlin> children._().in.loop(1){it.loops<5}{true}.groupCount.cap.next().findAll{it.value>1}
==>v[1]=3
==>v[4]=2
```

Now vertex `4` is included as a common ancestor.  It has children of vertex `6` and `5`.  Given the shared nature of vertex `4`, the `6` also share vertex `1` now so that ancestor is now shared by all three vertices.

**UPDATE:** The above answer is for TinkerPop 2.x and the following is for TinkerPop 3.x.

Given this tree:

```
gremlin> g.addV().property(id, 'A').as('a').
           addV().property(id, 'B').as('b').
           addV().property(id, 'C').as('c').
           addV().property(id, 'D').as('d').
           addV().property(id, 'E').as('e').
           addV().property(id, 'F').as('f').
           addV().property(id, 'G').as('g').
           addE('hasParent').from('a').to('b').
           addE('hasParent').from('b').to('c').
           addE('hasParent').from('d').to('c').
           addE('hasParent').from('c').to('e').
           addE('hasParent').from('e').to('f').
           addE('hasParent').from('g').to('f').iterate()
```

you can find the common ancestor with:

```
gremlin> g.V('A').
......1>   repeat(out('hasParent')).emit().as('x').
......2>   repeat(__.in('hasParent')).emit(hasId('D')).
......3>   select('x').limit(1)
==>v[C]
```

This topic is discussed more fully in the [TinkerPop recipes](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#_lowest_common_ancestor).